# Creating own Source in TM package

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I can create a Corpus from a big text file, but as results I have just one document in it.
In case this text file contains a parser text (say "ZZ") that can be used to generates documents in it, how can I instruct Corpus functions to use the "ZZ" delimiter as document identifier?

E.g.

Textfile:

```
ZZ APREPITANT (EU) Tabletten Quartalsbericht Nr. 1 Vorprojekt
Timing für EU Launch
Projektteam:
Dr. G, Dr. Gi, Dr. R, Hr. M, Fr. Braun, A. R;
Referenzprodukt:
ATC-Gruppe: (HPK: 411) EmendTM
ZZ BENDAMUSTIN (EU) - lyophil. Pulver Quartalsbericht Nr. 12 Zulassungsprojekt
Timing für EU Launch
Kristina R
Projektteam:
Dr. Britta E, Dr. H, Gieß, Holtz, Dr.F, Kristina R
Referenzprodukt: namehere (namehere)
ATC-Gruppe: Antineoplastische Mittel ­ alkylierende (L01A)
Geplante Produkte: 25, 100 mg lyophil. Pulver (2,5mg/ml) [ggf. 200mg Sondergröße]
API Hersteller:
namehere
qualif.:02+08/'11; (Q2/'14)
API Alternative: ---
DP Entwickler:
namehere
```

With this script corp has only one `Doc.Identifier`.

```
x <- read.csv(file_loc, header = FALSE)
corp <- Corpus(DataframeSource(x))
```

Is there any way to generate a corpus where "ZZ" identifies two different documents of same corpus? And is there a way to generate a custom source format so that this will be possible?

Comment: Do you mean you would like to split x into multiple "documents" where each document starts and ends with ZZ?  A strsplit() approach using regular expressions might preproocess x, before you use the tm package to create the corpus.

Comment: Yep, you are right and I thought about this. I just did not want to generate txt files or whatever to reread in everything in a corpus.